# Delphi Quick Reports - Cancel and Close Preview

Tags: delphi, quickreports

What's the best way to cancel a quick report whilst it is generating? I would like to cancel the report generation and automatically close the preview screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `QuickReport.Cancel` method. It's documented in the help file, at least for the QR 3.6 Pro version I have handy.

BTW, you should really mention which version of QuickReports you're using, as different versions have different functionality.